# consume browserified modules in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am new to javascript and I am facing some issues working with npm modules on the browser side. Could someone please direct me int he right direction ?

I have a module structure which is something like

add.js

```
 function add (a,b) {
  return a+b;
 }
 module.exports.add = add;
```

multiply.js

```
function multiply (a,b) {
  return a*b;
}
module.exports.multiply = multiply;
```

I have a consumer module called calculator.js which looks like:

```
var adder=require('./add');
var multiplier=require('./multiply');

console.log(adder.add(1,2));
console.log(multiplier.multiply(1,2));

function sum(a,b){
   return adder.add (a,b);
}

 function product(a,b){
   return multiplier.add (a,b);
}

module.exports.sum = sum;
module.exports.product=product;
```

When I do a 'node calculator.js', I get 3 & respectively.

I would now like to use this Calculator module in my browser. So I did the following :

1. browserify calculator.js > cal.js
2. Created an html file

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.2.0/require.js"></script>
    <script src='cal.js'></script>     

  </body>
</html>
```

3. This prints out 3 and 2 on console.
4. However I would like to use the calculator's methods doing a require of cal like

```js
  <script>
        var cal=require('cal');     
   </script>
```

This throws me an error saying

> 'Module name "cal" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use
>   require([])'

Any idea how do I get this running ? Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `require.js` for that.

Instead, you can tell Browserify to make the `calculator.js` module available for `require()`. This will also make a `require` function available for use in a browser:

```
$ browserify -r ./calculator.js:cal > cal.js
```

To use this in a browser:

```
<script src="cal.js"></script>
<script>
  var cal = require('cal');
  ...
</script>
```

More information [here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires).